# Pandas Compare Multiple Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame with 500 plus columns.
How can I do conditional compare on two sets of columns.

```
column_list_a = ['A', 'B', ..... 'N]  (say 100 columns )
column_list_b = ['O', 'P', ..... 'Z] (say 200 columns)
```

I tried:

```
df[column_list_a ].lt(df[column_list_b])
```

but it's not working.

The goal is to have all the column values in column_list_a should be less than all the column values in colum_list_b per row.

Also, I want to store the binary result in a new column.

Comment: What I understand is you want to compare the sum of the value for the 100 columns in a row vs the sum of the values for the other 200 columns in that row. The dataframe contains 300 columns in total?

Comment: No, compare each individual columns in 100 should be less than all other 200 columns. (Not the sum)

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution:

```
 df['combined1'] = other[column_list_a].values.tolist()
 df['combined2'] = other[column_list_b].values.tolist()
```

Now we have two new columns which has list of values from 100 and 200 columns respectively

```
 df['Result'] =  df.apply(lambda x: x['combined1']<x['combined2'], axis=1)
```

This can be generalized irrespective of number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare max of group a (the one supposed to be lesser) with min of group b (the one supposed to be greater).

So do for instance:

```py
res_comp=np.max(df[grp_A], axis=1)<np.min(df[grp_B], axis=1)
```

The whole setup (with dummy data):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame()
grp_A=list("ABCDEF")
grp_B=list("GHIJKLMNOPRST")

for l in list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRST"):
    if(l in grp_A):
        df[l]=np.random.randint(3,7,size=(3000))
    else:
        df[l]=np.random.randint(5,12,size=(3000))


res_comp=np.max(df[grp_A], axis=1)<np.min(df[grp_B], axis=1)

print(res_comp.value_counts())
```

Outputs:

```py
False    2860
True      140
dtype: int64
```